# get.php config to read and delete line from a file.txt

Tags: php, get

I have a `file.txt` with 500 lines, and I need config for `get.php` with a button. When I check it each time it reads the first line and deletes it from the `file.txt`.

For example : 
`file.txt` like this :

```
G: dns port user1 pass1

G: dns port user2 pass2 

G: dns port user3 pass3
```

I need after the first click of the button to view this line in the page :

`G: dns port user1 pass1`

After that the `file.txt` will look like this :

```
G: dns port user2 pass2

G: dns port user3 pass3
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to php, thanks for help.

```
$file = fopen("/var/www/test/file.txt","r"); 
while(! feof($file)) { 
    echo fgets($file). "<br />"; 
} 
fclose($file);
```

this is the second thing i have

```
$text = file_get_contents('/var/www/test/file.txt');
$textArray = explode("\n", $text);
$randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($textArray);
$randPhrase = $textArray[$randArrayIndexNum];
```

Comment: So what have you tried _yourself_ so far to solve this task?

Comment: i have this 

<?php
$file = fopen("/var/www/test/file.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }

fclose($file);
?>

but how to delete line from file.txt , and regenerate the second ?

this is my problem

Comment: Well, 1. you have to open the file for writing, not for reading. 2. you need to read the whole file, line by line, to be able to output all of that again, skipping the first line, which you will output to the browser instead. 3. you do not need to close the file, nor do you need the closing php tag at the end. Just drop both.

Comment: can you please give an exemple tou use it
really i m newer in php and i need to learn more about it

Comment: i have this too , but it s generate a line without order .

<?php
$text = file_get_contents('/var/www/test/file.txt');
$textArray = explode("\n", $text);
$randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($textArray);
$randPhrase = $textArray[$randArrayIndexNum];
?>

Comment: Please do not add code in comments here, you can see yourself that it is not readable. Please use the `edit` button below your question to add code to the question itself, as I did for your first comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely crude but working implementation:

```
<?php

define ('INPUT_FILE', '/tmp/CCcam.cfg');

function unshiftLineFromFile($fileName) {
    $fileContents = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $firstLine = array_shift($fileContents);
    file_put_contents($fileName, implode(PHP_EOL, $fileContents));
    return $firstLine;
}

echo sprintf("%s<br>\n", htmlentities(unshiftLineFromFile(INPUT_FILE)));
```

This won't scale for obvious reasons. First it reads the whole file into memory with each iteration, that obviously is an issue for bigger files. Then it always re-creates the whole file, however there is no real easy way to do this. Operating systems simply do not offer efficient methods to do such task. Which leads to third: you should use a database instead of files...

Comment: thank you freind , it s helpful
but i have just this result
G: dns port user1 pass1
\n

when i click the second time i have the same line

you can check it yourself here

http://panel.azshare.tv/get.php

Comment: i can t use database because i have program how need tis CCcam.cfg as this format.

Comment: Two reasons I can think of: 1. you may simply have a caching issue. Try using a "deep reload" in your browser... Do you get the second line then? If so: you have to add caching control headers to your output. 2. Your script may not have write access to the file. In that case you should see an error in your http servers error log file and you have to change the file permissions such that the http server process can actually write the file and the directory.

Comment: Why can't you use a database? Write a trivial import script for your input files.

Comment: thanks brother , i set chmod 777 to the file and it all ok now

but stil 1 problem it s how to delete "\n" from the output

Comment: There are next to no situations where I can imagine file permissions of 0777 really being required. But anyway, fine you solved that issue...

Comment: About the `\n`: I assume you copied the code above too soon, whilst I was still editing it. Note the double quotes (`"`) in the `echo` command. If you still use single quotes (`'`) that explains your issue. Sorry, I changed that as soon as I realized the issue.